# rethinkDB pluck generated_key from insert python

Tags: python, rethinkdb, reql

Essentially, I'm trying to get the generated key for a single record insert. Something like:

```
rethinkdb.table('test').insert(request.data).pluck('generated_keys')[0].run(connection)
```

and have it return something like:

```
{
    "id": "61fa30de-cfb1-4133-ae86-cf6e4f1a011e"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just want to give some tips so that you can figure this out later. First, you can use `typeOf` to find the type of data.

```
r.table('dummy').insert({f: "foo"}).typeOf()
"OBJECT"
```

So you know if returns an object. Next, you go to RethinkDB document, try to find some similar function. A good guess is `get_field` http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/get_field/

And get_field can be called on object:

> sequence.getField(attr) → sequence
>
> singleSelection.getField(attr) → value
>
> object.getField(attr) → value

Let's see what it returns it:

```
r.table('dummy').insert({f: "foo"}).getField('generated_keys').typeOf()
"ARRAY"
```

Let's find a command to return an element in array. You can go over the document again and will be noticed `nth` command to return a n-th element from an array. Therefore, we can do this now:

```
r.table('dummy').insert({f: "foo"}).getField('generated_keys').nth(0)
"c2b1bf69-a926-4c27-b1a6-011d47c700df"
```

Let's try to simplify it. Using `getField` is annyoing. To make it short, you can use bracket `()` to get a single field from object

```
r.table('dummy').insert({f: "foo"})('generated_keys').nth(0)
"77f4aca6-9219-494e-9998-23eb9abcd5e0"
```

But using `nth` also field annyoying a bit. Can we make it short. Luckily bracket can also be call on array.http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/bracket/

> The () command also accepts integer arguments as array offsets, like
>   the nth command.

Combine everything we have:

```
r.table('dummy').insert({f: "foo"})('generated_keys')(0)
```

This is all run direcly on Data Explorer but I think you can easily convert them into Python by looking at JavaScript and translate into Python.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, If you want to return an array of all primary keys for the inserted documents, you can do the following:

```
 r.table('test').insert({ "hello": 'world' })['generated_keys'].run(conn)
```

If you want the query to return the primary key of the first inserted document as a string, you can do the following:

```
r.table('test').insert({ "hello": 'world' })['generated_keys'][0].run(conn)
```